# How to submit an topology to a specify storm worker node?

Tags: apache-storm

Assumed that I have a storm cluster formed with three servers, named as `server1, server2, server3`.

`Server1` runs as master node, `server2 and 3` run as worker node.

When I submit a `topology` to `Server1`, it always distribute the topology to run on `Server2`.

But there is something wrong with `Server2`(new submitted `topologies` can run but don't truly work, and I don't know why), so I want to change the server that the `topologies` would run on.

And here is my ***question***:

How could I submit my topologies to a specify worker server?

Comment: You can't, it is storm's role to distribute the load of your topology accross workers.

Comment: I agree with @zenbeni, we tried to launch specific supervisors first and submit topology, then launch another supervisors/topology when we had to assign specific machines for a topology. But since topology can restart at anytime, this does not fully guarantee topology assignment to specific machines.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you confuse workers with supervisors. Supervisors are running on each node in your cluster and started when starting up the Storm cluster. Workers are started by supervisors if a topology is submitted. You can configure the max number of workers for each supervisor in storm.yaml. Nimbus is communicating with supervisors only (via Zookeeper): see https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Tutorial.html

Furthermore, you can implement a custom scheduler in Storm, and thus influence to which nodes (ie, supervisors) a topology is submitted to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I'll check on those links :)

Comment: The second link doesn't seem to be relevant anymore, do you mind updating it or directing me to any other source that guides about custom supervisor selection at topology startup?

Comment: I don't have any other resource how this can be done at hand. Sorry.